# How to pass an ajax value to php?

Tags: javascript, php

Currently, I am working on web application using php. I am trying to pass a value from ajax to php and it always says `undefined index`. Actually, this is the first time I am developing a web application that's why, I don't understand much about the fundamentals of it. Without reading the documentation of the programming languages I am using, I started to practice it that's why.

So here's the code:

php:

```
<?php
    include_once('pConfig.php');
    if (!isset($_POST['cID'])){
        $ciCode = $_POST['cID'];
    }
    $strSQL = "SELECT csi_personal_info.ci_ID, csi_personal_info.Fname, csi_personal_info.Mname, 
    csi_personal_info.Lname, csi_personal_info.Age, csi_personal_info.Birthdate, csi_personal_info.Status, 
    csi_personal_info.Religion, csi_contact_info.home_number, csi_contact_info.personal_ph_number, csi_contact_info.email, 
    csi_contact_info.pro_address, csi_contact_info.pre_address, ci_account_info.ciCODe, ci_account_info.LoanType,
    ci_account_info.Bank, ci_account_info.Amount, ci_account_info.Status FROM csi_personal_info INNER JOIN csi_contact_info ON csi_personal_info.ci_ID = csi_contact_info.ci_ID 
    INNER JOIN ci_account_info ON csi_contact_info.ci_ID = ci_account_info.ci_ID WHERE ci_account_info.ciCODe = '$ciCode'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
    if (!$result) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($db));
        exit();
    }
    $json = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    previewReport();
});

 function previewReport(){
    var cID = window.localStorage.getItem('ciCode');
    var xdata = "{'cID':'" + cID + "'}";
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../back_php_Code/pInspectRecords.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: xdata,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        },
         error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
   });   
}
```

Comment: Output your POST and see what you are sending. That looks like you are trying to send a JSON string.. Otherwise I think it should be `var xdata = {'cID': cID };`

Comment: Where and are you setting "ciCode" in the local storage? From your code, looks like you could be trying to use a storage item that has not been set yet. Also, the undefined index, which line is it referring to? It should say on the right hand side of your console where you saw the 'undefined index' part.

Comment: @user3783243 That's correct, and also a fix is needed in on the PHP side of things. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my problem with this: I have corrected the `TYPE:` in ajax, also, the isset in php code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    previewReport();
});

 function previewReport(){
    var cID = window.localStorage.getItem('ciCode');
    alert(cID);
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '../back_php_Code/pInspectRecords.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {'cID': cID},
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        },
         error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
   });   
}

<?php
    include_once('pConfig.php');
    if (!isset($ciCODe)){
        $ciCode = $_GET['cID'];
    }   
    $strSQL = "SELECT csi_personal_info.ci_ID, csi_personal_info.Fname, csi_personal_info.Mname, 
    csi_personal_info.Lname, csi_personal_info.Age, csi_personal_info.Birthdate, csi_personal_info.Status, 
    csi_personal_info.Religion, csi_contact_info.home_number, csi_contact_info.personal_ph_number, csi_contact_info.email, 
    csi_contact_info.pro_address, csi_contact_info.pre_address, ci_account_info.ciCODe, ci_account_info.LoanType,
    ci_account_info.Bank, ci_account_info.Amount, ci_account_info.Status FROM csi_personal_info INNER JOIN csi_contact_info ON csi_personal_info.ci_ID = csi_contact_info.ci_ID 
    INNER JOIN ci_account_info ON csi_contact_info.ci_ID = ci_account_info.ci_ID WHERE ci_account_info.ciCODe = '$ciCode'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $strSQL);
    if (!$result) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($db));
        exit();
    }
    $json = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, we want an array and not a string for the `xdata` variable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    previewReport();
});

 function previewReport(){
    var cID = window.localStorage.getItem('ciCode');
    var xdata = {'cID':cID};
        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../back_php_Code/pInspectRecords.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: xdata,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        },
         error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
   });   
}
```

This then means, that the AJAX script will send data to your PHP script via `$_POST["cID"]`.

To make your PHP code work, you'll need to change the following

```
if (!isset($_POST['cID'])){
    $ciCode = $_POST['cID'];
}
```

to this

```
$ciCode = "";
/* Check if cID is set */
if (isset($_POST['cID'])){
     $ciCode = $_POST['cID'];
}
```

Doing this, prevents null values and unexpected errors within your script. Your orginial code was preventing `$ciCode` from being set to `$_POST['cID']` as you were using `!isset` which means `not set`.

Comment: Also the `if` should extend for the whole block and parameterized query should be used.

Comment: This could be true, but I left it out as I wasn't sure on what exactly sure OP's script was doing. @user3783243